# HTML + CSS: Child div not displayed if parent div's bottom value not set

Tags: html, css

My problem is that the div which id is "problem" is not displayed. If its parent div has `bottom:0` then the div "problem" is displayed correctly and parent div's height is 100% of browser window height.

I just do not want to use full height of window. The height of div "problem" should be so that there is always 30px bottom margin. So, no extra height, but 30px bottom margin.

```html
    <div style="z-index:999;display:block;position:fixed;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;height:100%;min-height:100%;background:rgba(65,77,117,.5);">
      <div style="display:block;clear:both;position:relative;width:403px;background-color:#FFFFFF;overflow:visible;top:0;/*bottom:0;*/left:50%;margin-left:-240px;position:fixed;z-index:100;">
        <div style="position:absolute;left:30px;right:30px;top:5px;">Hello</div>

        <h2>Header</h2>

        <div id="problem" style="position:absolute;top:78px;bottom:30px;left:30px;right:30px;overflow-y:auto;">
          <div style="width:100%;display:inline-block;">This should be displayed<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a</div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `#problem` `<div>` has an [**overflow**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/) of `auto`, which hides the contents of the element if the contents escape the bounds. Your `#problem` `<div>` has a height of `0`, so there's nowhere for the `<div>` inside of it to display.

Simply removing `overflow: auto` from `#problem` fixes this problem (by restoring the `overflow` to `visible` by default).

```html
<div style="z-index:999;display:block;position:fixed;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;height:100%;min-height:100%;background:rgba(65,77,117,.5);">
  <div style="display:block;clear:both;position:relative;width:403px;background-color:#FFFFFF;overflow:visible;top:0;/*bottom:0;*/left:50%;margin-left:-240px;position:fixed;z-index:100;">
    <div style="position:absolute;left:30px;right:30px;top:5px;">Hello</div>
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <div id="problem" style="position:absolute;top:78px;bottom:30px;left:30px;right:30px;overflow:auto;height:20px;">
      <div style="width:100%;display:inline-block;">This should be displayed</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that `overflow: visible` will not show a scrollbar. If you would like to retain a scrollbar (although not illustrated in your question), you need to provide `#problem` with a `height` large enough to fully contain any elements within. I've gone with `20px` in this example:

```html
<div style="z-index:999;display:block;position:fixed;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;height:100%;min-height:100%;background:rgba(65,77,117,.5);">
  <div style="display:block;clear:both;position:relative;width:403px;background-color:#FFFFFF;overflow:visible;top:0;/*bottom:0;*/left:50%;margin-left:-240px;position:fixed;z-index:100;">
    <div style="position:absolute;left:30px;right:30px;top:5px;">Hello</div>
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <div id="problem" style="position:absolute;top:78px;bottom:30px;left:30px;right:30px;overflow:auto;height:20px;">
      <div style="width:100%;display:inline-block;">This should be displayed</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Now I cannot see the vertical scrollbar if it is needed.

Comment: Then please update your question to clearly specify the **intended results**, and include a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You did not mention a scrollbar at all in your question, and the `overflow` is directly responsible for your problem as it stands.

Comment: @xms -- I've updated my answer to provide an alternative approach if you want to show a scrollbar. Considering `overflow` removes any scrollbars (which aren't visible or mentioned in your sample problem), the other option is to give `#problem` a `height` that is large enough to fully show any elements contained with.

Comment: Thanks for a good try. The height 20px is not enough if there is more text on the child div.

Comment: ...That's why I said "*large enough to fully show any elements contained*". Adjust accordingly.